# Wordpress show posts from children terms of a taxonomy term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop

I was a little hard for me to explain what I'm trying to achieve in the title so I will explain my setup much more detailed here. I tried to find an answer searching here and other sites but couldn't find anything that fits what I'm trying to do.

I have a a custom taxonomy called "products_cat" this custom taxonomy has different terms as parent categories: "Electronics", "Computer", "Home Appliances", etc. And then under each of those terms I have more subcategories like under Electronics for example I have "TV", "Audio", "Home Theaters", "MP3",etc.

So the thing I'm trying to do is to have within the taxonomy-product_cat.php a code that display the current chosen Taxonomy (suppose Electronics) and then have the titles of all children and the products under each one of those.

Thanks.

Comment: How is this different from showing posts in that term? All the posts in the child terms will still show if you look for the parent term...

Comment: Because as I explain on the message I need to show the products ordered by title, being this title the name of the children taxonomy of that parent one.
If I query to show products under Electronics, I will just get a bunch of products without any order, TV products will be mixed with audio, home theaters, mp3.

Comment: So the root of your question is you want to know how to get all child terms of a given term?